# Banach Algebra Isomorphisms

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

I'm looking through some notes on algebra isomorphisms and have encountered two slightly different notions of isomorphisms, depending on whether the algebras are Banach or not. All algebras are assumed to be complex.

Let $A,B$ be algebras over $\mathbb{C}$. We say that $A, B$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection $F:A\rightarrow B$ such that $\forall\ {x,y\in A};\ \forall\ \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb C:$
$$F(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lambda F(x)+\mu F(y);\ F(xy)=F(x)F(y).$$

In the case that $A,B$ are Banach algebras, then we require $F:A\rightarrow B$ to be a bounded linear operator which is invertible, and satisfies
$$F(xy)=F(x)F(y);\ \forall_{x,y\in A}.$$

Since $F$ is invertible, (I think, at least) then we are ensured that $F$ is bijective; hence we 'hit' the definition for non-Banach algebras.  I'm wondering why we require boundedness in the case of Banach algebras.

Comment: Because we want an isomorphism of *Banach* algebras; the norm is part of the structure of a Banach algebra so we want to preserve it. For example we might want to know whether a sequence converges in one Banach algebra, and we can relate it via an isomorphism to the corresponding sequence in an isomorphic Banach algebra, but only if isomorphisms know something about the norm.

Comment: Thank you. Are you able explain how boundedness ‘preserves’ the norm?

Comment: Really the definition should ask for an isometry (which would preserve the norm in the strictest possible sense) but I think that might follow in this case from bounded + invertible, at least if the algebras are unital. I haven't checked though.